# Why function scala.reflect.runtime.universe.classTag[T] is missing?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm using apache Spark and one of my subroutine is to check if T: ClassTag of an RDD[T: ClassTag] is a subclass of Map.

I've checked many source on scala reflection and they all suggest the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
if classTag[T] <:< classTag[Map[_,_]] {do something...}
```

however the classTag function seems to be missing, I only see typeOf and weakTypeOf which obviously doesn't work here (because of type erasure: ClassTag of an RDD carries far less information than a TypeTag). Is it moved somewhere else in a later scala version? I'm using 2.10.4

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in `scala.reflect`package

```
scala> import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect._

scala> classTag[Option[Int]]
res45: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Option[Int]] = scala.Option
```

See the most modern [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)

For subtyping check you shoud use typeTag, like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> typeTag[Int].tpe <:< typeTag[Any].tpe
res54: Boolean = true

scala> typeTag[Int].tpe <:< typeTag[Boolean].tpe
res55: Boolean = false
```

You can obtain `TypeTag` in the same way as `ClassTag`. If you want to obtain `TypeTag` from `ClassTag` with unerased type:

```
scala> def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](ct: ClassTag[T]) = typeTag[T]
getTypeTag: [T](ct: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

scala> getTypeTag(classTag[Int])
res52: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int] = TypeTag[Int]
```

If you just need to check subtyping between two known types:

```
scala> typeOf[Int] <:< typeOf[Boolean]
res56: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I ask one more question? The operator <:< was marked @deprecated after 2.10 as well: (Use scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag for subtype checking instead). But it definitely won't work since ClassTag is all I have, how to circumvent/suppress this warning?

Comment: Got it: classOf[Map[_,_]].isAssignableFrom(classTag[T].runtimeClass) the function name is so weird I hardly read it without thinking its useless

Comment: I really want to use the scala way, unfortunately Spark RDD won't let me: it doesn't provide TypeTag, probably due to legacy code migration